# How to make an Access TextBox, with a Numberic Value, Equal to DLookup with the TextBox as the Criteria

Tags: ms-access, textbox, lookup

I really have no idea why this doesn't work, but I am trying to get the following to work:

```
If Me.Text1 = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Test1_Table.Field1= _
     & Me.Text1") Then
   MsgBox "It works"
Else
End If
```

The above code is a test code for a larger project that I am working on, so the table and field names are just for testing.  Also, Field1 is a numberic field.  Basically, when I enter 1 within Text1, I would like the DLookup feature to find 1 within Test1_Table.Field1 and give me a message stating that it works.  I am able to get this to work with string values such as:

```
If Me.Text1 = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Test1_Table.Field1='" _
    & Me.Text1 & "'")Then
```

Likewise this works, when 1 is entered in the Text1:

```
If 1 = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Test1_Table.Field1= _
    & Me.Text1") Then
```

However, I've tried:

```
If Me.Text1 = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Test1_Table.Field1= _
    & Forms!TestSearch_Form!Text0)Then
```

and

```
If Me.Text1 = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Test1_Table.Field1= _
    & Forms!TestSearch_Form!Text0)Then
```

etc...

I've tried many different combinations and it seems as though I cannot get the two to equal, when dealing with numeric values.  Does anyone know what I am missing or have any ideas?

Thank you,

Damion

Comment: In the first code example, "Test1_Table.Field1= & Me.Text1") should actually read "Test1_Table.Field1=" & Me.Text1).  However, this still does not work.

Thanks,

DFM

Comment: Your quotes are mostly in the wrong place. If this is a typo, then you also need to be sure that your types are correct. Comparing decimal numbers can be problematic.

Comment: @Remou: They twice said "numberic" [sic] and once "numeric". As you doubt know, in ACE/Jet SQL syntax, NUMERIC is a synonym for DECIMAL... @DFM: are we talking about DECIMAL values here?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
 If Not IsNull(DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Field1=" & Me.Text1)) Then
```

This will only work if Field1 is defined as a numeric field, you will need delimiters if it is a datetime or text field.

EDIT:

The above statement is either equal to the value of Me.Text1, or is null. Another way to use DllookUp would be to say:

```
 SomeVar=DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Field1=" & Me.Text1)
```

SomeVar will be either null, that is, not found, or return the value or Field1, which is equal to Me.Text1, because that is what we asked for in the Where statement. You can see from this that it is pointless to return the value of Field1, it is either found andequal to text1, or not found, and null. The olnly reason for getting the value of DlookUp is if you are looking up some other value or calculation in the table.

After this, it is important to remember that you are looking for an exact match and decimal values can be quite different far to the right of the decimal point, where you are unlikely to look.

Comment: Thanks for the response - For my lookup to work, I need to have the DLookup equal to the textbox.  I don't think I can use the above code, in this case.  Field1 is set as a numeric field.  What is wierd is that - If 1 = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Field1=" & Me.Text1) Then ... works when I enter 1 in the textbox, but when I replace the 1, after the "if" with Me.Text1 and enter 1 in the textbox, the lookup doesn't recognize the value 1 in field1.

Comment: Why not use a DCount() in place of DLookup()? What you want to know is not the returned value (you already know that), but the count of records. That is, unless you've boiled down your example too far, and you really are returning a value other than the one you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sWhere as String
sWhere = "Test1_Table.Field1=" & Me.Text1
If CInt(Me.Text1)=DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", sWhere) Then         
     MsgBox "It works" 
Else
   'do something else
End If
```

Trying to do too much vba inside the DLookup could be an issue?

Comment: Thank you for your response - Unfortunatley, this is not working as well.  I keep getting "do something else", which is telling me that the code is not looking for a numeric value.  For additional information, field1 has four records, which are 1,2,3,4.  When I try testing the code I enter a 1 in the textbox, to make it as simple as possible.  This might be a limitation with DLookup (?)

Comment: I was able to duplicate your test failure, but it worked when used: CInt(Me.Text1) = ...

Answer (score 0):

If CInt(Me.Text1) = DLookup("Field1", "Test1_Table", "Test1_Table.Field1=" & Me.Text1) Then...

The above code works perfectly.  Thanks to Guiness, I was able to utilize my original code and just add CInt to the if statement.

Also, thank you everyone for your input.

DFM